# Where can i save information to be displayed by my Android App

Tags: java, android, android-layout

where should i save the information i want my app to display When selected,with out using a server because i want my content(includes a combination of text and images) to be available offline and which format can i use to this in Android?

Comment: You can put images in res/drawable, text in res/values/string.xml. Alternatively and depending how you plan to use the images you can save them in res/raw which gives you more of a raw file access.

Comment: well  i plan to use both text and images at the same time because the app i am creating is like a guide which has both images and text explaining a topic

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Perhaps show us your code and how you have attempted to solve this?

Comment: I developed a tourism guide some time ago. My sugestion is you store the text in sqlite database and the images in res/raw folder.

Comment: OK so how will i combine both of them because what i want is making something which looks like a tutorial which is step by step also displaying images after text explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can save it into a SQLite database file, doing it directly as taught by many tutorials, or using the Room Persistence Library, where you can find a nice and easy tutorial here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Answer (score -1):

[Storage options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), pretty nice listing and explanation

- **Shared Preferences**: Store private primitive data in key-value pairs, is a good idea for small simple data like flags or user preferences.
- **Internal Storage**: Store private data on the device memory, basically you can write files to a private area for your applications, will also show up as space consumed by your application user data in settings.
- **External Storage**: Store public data on the shared external storage, same as internal storage but the directly is public and not private to your application, user and other applications can see this directory.
- **SQLite Databases**: Store structured data in a private database, you can place the database where you want (internal/external) provides some nice mechanism for CRUD operations.
- **Network Connection**: Store data on the web with your own network
  server.